# Pull 5 entries from DB, modify entries, put those 5 entries into an array so I can find the average

Tags: php, arrays

I am pulling 5 entries from a database, which is working fine. I then do some math for each entry to get different numbers. Those 5 numbers will show up next to eachother. I need to put those 5 entries into an array, and then select the average of those 5, so I just have one solid number.

From the mysql_fetch_array, I pulled $last_score, $blue_rating, and $blue_slope for the latest 5 entries. Now here is where I'm at:

```
$query_p1 = "SELECT * FROM scorecards WHERE player_id='$player_id' LIMIT 5";
        $result_p1 = mysql_query($query_p1);
        while ($row_p1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_p1)) {
            $blue_rating = $row_p1["blue_rating"];
            $blue_slope = $row_p1["blue_slope"];
            $last_score = $row_p1["total_score"];

$handicap = (((($last_score - $blue_rating) * 113) / $blue_slope) * .96);

echo "$handicap <br>";

}
```

Those 5 echo's are what I need in a single array with the average of the 5. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can make an array with `$handicap[] = `. Then use `array_sum()` and divide by `5`.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo "$handicap <br>";
```

Put

```
$handicaps[]= $handicap;
```

Then outside the loop you could do

```
echo array_sum($handicaps)/5;
```